# How did Adam got his intellect?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, language, adam

The tradition says that Adam was created grown up and extremely intelligent. We know that his body was formed from the earth and his soul was blown into the body and then he became a living (talking) soul.

Do the sources reveal the details of his intelligence, was he taught, talked to or programmed wirelessly, was he treated by G-d himself or by an angel as all fetuses do, and especially **what did he know and what he didn't know**?

This is very important to me to know what he knew to start with, to know how he acted later. For example, if he knew Hebrew, how come he didn't know the names of the animals? Or if he was so smart, how come he didn't know he needs a woman to fulfill his needs?